# PHP explode without limit

Tags: php, parameters, explode

The explode function below has a positive limit parameter of 2. What does this parameter do, and how can I remove it?

```
$array = explode(' ', $str, 2);
```

Comment: what does the manual say it does:"    If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.

    If the limit parameter is negative, all components except the last -limit are returned.

    If the limit parameter is zero, then this is treated as 1.
" as to removeing it -delete key

Comment: Tip: You can look up the documentation for any built-in PHP function by visiting php.net/function-name.  For `explode`, the URL would be [`http://php.net/explode`](http://php.net/explode).  **Reading the documentation is *always* faster than asking here!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the array will have three elements , depending upon the value of $str , first two elements would be strings separated by space . The remaining part of the string will be the thrid element.

If $str is very long and all you need is first two elements of array then there is no point of removing 2 , latter if you like can do `$array2 = explode(' ',$array[2]);`

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter is optional.

```
$array = explode(' ', $str);
```

Try this for splitting the $str with space (' '). No limit on items.